# CSS: Offset child element from center of parent div without moving other child elements?

Tags: html, css, next.js, tailwind-css

Here's a piece of sample code for my closest attempt at what I'm trying to achieve:

```
<nav className="flex flex-row justify-between items-center w-full h-[100px]">
    <div className="flex flex-row items-center sm:pl-0 ml-auto">
        <div className="mr-10">
            Child 1
        </div>
        <p className="text-center">Child 2</p>
    </div>

    <div className="ml-auto">
        <p>Child 3</p>
    </div>
</nav>
```

I want Child 3 to be aligned to the right, and Child 2 aligned in the center. If I remove Child 1, Child 2 will be aligned exactly in the center. However, when I try to add in Child 1 and slightly offset it to the left of the center, it will push Child 2 towards the right so that it is no longer aligned in the center.

Do I need to use absolute positioning for this or is there another way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if you really don't want the positions of the other elements affected, absolute positioning could be a CSS-only solution with your current HTML structure:

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.4.1"></script>

<nav class="flex flex-row justify-between items-center w-full h-[100px]">
  <div class="flex flex-row items-center sm:pl-0 ml-auto relative">
    <div class="mr-10 absolute right-0 top-0 w-max">
        Child 1
    </div>
    <p class="text-center">Child 2</p>
  </div>

  <div class="ml-auto">
    <p>Child 3</p>
  </div>
</nav>
```

You could also consider a grid layout too, for another CSS-only solution, preserving your HTML structure:

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.4.1"></script>

<nav class="grid grid-cols-[1fr_auto_1fr] items-center w-full h-[100px]">
  <div class="grid col-span-2 grid-cols-subgrid">
    <div class="mr-10 -ml-10 col-start-2 row-span-full">
        Child 1
    </div>
    <p class="text-center col-start-2 row-span-full">Child 2</p>
  </div>

  <div class="justify-self-end col-start-3">
    <p>Child 3</p>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Appreciate it. The content of Child 2 is dynamic and so can vary in width, which was my primary concern with absolute positioning. However it works regardless of the size of the Child 2 div. Thanks!